# Can anyone teach me how to answer this question???

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

$\frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{{x}^{a_1}}{1-x^{d_1}}+\cdots+\frac{{x}^{a_n}}{1-x^{d_n}}$ for all $x\neq 1$.Then show that $d_1,\cdots,d_n$ cannot be all distinct.Also note that $a_1,\cdots,a_n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $d_1,\cdots,d_n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $ n\geq 2$.

Comment: Hint: the biggest $d_k$ must appear at least twice.  (This is the key step in one slick proof that the integers cannot be partitioned into 2 or more arithmetic progressions all of whose moduli are distinct $-$ and indeed the largest modulus must be repeated.)

Comment: I will be grateful if you give me a detailed solution for this problem....

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I have heard that you are the youngest person who has lectured at Harvard? I would like to congratulate you on your achievements.

Comment: So I'm told, yes.  Thanks for the congratulations, though it happened in 1993 and I'm not nearly as young now as I was at the time...

Comment: Oh, you are welcome. Absolutely welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.First I will take you through a link of this problem to a deeper problem.

Since the above applies for all $x$ in the range $(0,1)$, let us expand $\frac{x}{1-x}$ (which we can do at least in this region), it will come out to be $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n$. We can do the same for the right side as well:
$$
\frac{x^{a_1}}{1-x^{d_1}}+...+\frac{x^{a_n}}{1-x^{d_n}}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{a_1+id_1} + ... + \sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{a_n+id_n}
$$
Each of these series are absolutely convergent which allows us to rearrange it in the following fashion after equating both left and right hand side:
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n x^{a_k+id_k}
$$
Now we compare coefficients on both sides,because equality as uniform convergent power series is equivalent to equality of coefficients. This would imply the following statement:
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists a_k,b_k \text{ such that } n \equiv a_k\mod b_k 
$$
Thus the integers have been partitioned exactly into a set of arithmetic progressions. Thus, the problem you have stated is equivalent to the problem of splitting the integers into arithmetic progressions of distinct steps.

Now we get to your solution. Let $d_1$ be the maximum of the $d_n$ without loss of generality. Write your equation down:
$$
\frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{x^{a_1}}{1-x^{d_1}}+...+\frac{x^{a_n}}{1-x^{d_n}}
$$

Note that the series above converge uniformly and absolutely on the complex disc $|x|<1$. The left side only has poles at $x=1$ (a pole is "basically" a value for which the denominator of a function vanishes). The first term of the right side has $d_1$ maximal, which means it has poles at the $d_1$th roots of unity, which are the complex solutions to the equation $x^{d_n}=1$. Let $\psi$ be any primitive root from those above, which is not $1$ if there are at least two distinct terms in the summation, because some $d_i>1$ on that occasion.

When $x \to \psi$, we get $\frac{\psi}{1-\psi}$ on the left hand side. On the right side, however, we have for some $d_2 \neq d_1$ wlog,
$$
\frac{x^{a_2}}{1-x^{d_2}} \to \frac{\psi^{a_2}}{1-\psi^{d_2}}
$$

Where $\psi^{d_2} \neq 1$ as $d_2 < d_1$, which is finite, but the term $\frac{x^{a_1}}{1-x^{d_1}}$ will go to infinity, by definition of $\psi$. In short, I let both sides go to $\psi$ for a specific $\psi$ and obtained a contradiction to the fact that there are two different terms of the above sum. The net result is that the $d_i$ are all the same, and the partition of the integers is a rather trivial partition.